# Theano OSError on function declaration

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gpu, theano

On declaration of a Theano symbolic function, I get an OSError and traceback.  Interestingly enough, the same code functions on a different machine.  One machine is configured to use the GPU, while the other (with the error) is CPU-only. Has anyone else experienced this sort of behavior and have a clue how to proceed?

```
  File "classifiers/mlp.py", line 37, in predict
    f = theano.function([X], Y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/compile/function.py", line 223, in function
    profile=profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 511, in pfunc
    on_unused_input=on_unused_input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1332, in orig_function
    defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1198, in create
    _fn, _i, _o = self.linker.make_thunk(input_storage=input_storage_lists)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/link.py", line 489, in make_thunk
    output_storage=output_storage)[:3]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/vm.py", line 882, in make_all
    no_recycling))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/op.py", line 618, in make_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cc.py", line 992, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cc.py", line 935, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1372, in cthunk_factory
    key=key, fn=self.compile_cmodule_by_step, keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 1005, in module_from_key
    module = next(compile_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1287, in compile_cmodule_by_step
    preargs=preargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 1962, in compile_str
    p_out = output_subprocess_Popen(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/misc/windows.py", line 73, in output_subprocess_Popen
    p = subprocess_Popen(command, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/theano/misc/windows.py", line 36, in subprocess_Popen
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo, **params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1153, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it was triggered on declaration of Theano's symbolic function, but it was a simple memory issue.  Cutting down on memory usage solved the problem for me.